# Identification of an inductor

Tags: inductance

[image][image]

Hi, I'm currently trying to figure out what is the significance of this number on top of an inductor. Does it mean the value of inductance?

Comment: Are you sure that it's an inductor? Can you put a larger photo showing its designator?

Comment: it shows L1 besides it

Comment: Strange. Looks very much like an resistor. Can you zoom out ever further?

Comment: I'd say 30uH, but they could be resistors as well *(In fact, I suspect that the factory/designer has decided to put 30mR resistors for some reason, even if the design itself contains inductors)*.

Comment: @RohatKılıç +1 on that. Far from unheard of.

Comment: Maybe if you could get a bigger pic on more surrounding components, so we get a clue about the purpose of these? Or a schematic would be even better.

Comment: Maybe i will try to unsolder it and measure it first using LCR meter

Comment: On LCR meter, it shows -3H at 100KHz

Comment: Am i missing something here?

Comment: Edit your question and put the measurement details so that everyone can see the updated question.